# How to find available cars between date ranges

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

Thare two tables:
cars

```
id | name          | count_cars  
1  | Volvo S60     | 3  
2  | Tesla model 3 | 2
```

reservations

```
id | car_id | date_from        | date_to  
1  | 1      | 2017-05-02 10:00 | 2017-05-05 10:00  
2  | 1      | 2017-05-01 10:00 | 2017-05-03 10:00  
3  | 2      | 2017-05-03 10:00 | 2017-05-04 10:00
```

The first table is cars list, where count is number of cars this model.
The second table is list of reservations of cars.

Problem:
The user enters two dates, and the system must provide a list of the cars that will be available between these dates.
I want, having dates that the user enters and the dates of booking cars from the second table, determine how many and which cars are booked for these dates.
There are situations when the car is partially reserved between dates, in such cases the car also needs to be considered booked.

How through one sql request to receive the list and quantity of the available 
 cars?
car_id|count_available

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like you are trying to get people to just write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical overlaps query.  You can use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from cars c
where not exists (select 1
                  from reservations r
                  where r.carid = c.id and
                        r.startdate <= $enddate and
                        r.enddate >= $startdate
                 );
```

A overlap between two time frames occurs when one starts before the second ends and the first ends after the second starts.

Note that the `<=` and `>=` might really be `<` and/or `>`, depending on how you count the ends of the periods.

Answer (score 1):

What about a

```
SELECT r.car_id, count(r.car_id)
FROM cars c, reservations r
WHERE r.date_from <= :user_input_from 
AND r.date_to >= :user_input_to
AND r.car_id = c.id group by r.car_id;
```

EDIT: As suggested below changed to <= and >=.

Comment: Only suggested edit to this great, concise answer:

WHERE r.date_from <= :user_input_from 
AND r.date_to >= :user_input_to